# How to call a function from Python code to C# Library?

Tags: python, c#, python-3.x

I do not want to run the Python code from C#. I want to access few functions from the Python Program and use it inside my C# Code.

I have checked solutions and have found that run Python Script.
I do not want that.

I have a python code function like this:

```
import numpy as np

def test(abc): # abc is numpy array
    total = np.sum(abc)
    return total
```

I want to call this test function in C# code. Please let me know how I can do this.

Comment: You have to create a wrapper and then run  it which will be same as running a regular python script which I guess you don't want to. So if python code is not editable or no separate wrapper is written it may not be possible.